# lektor checkboxes `[u'` ouput error?

Tags: list, checkbox, lektor

my first attemp in lektor: I want to create my own Data Model for architectural works record.
I have a wierd ouput for `checkboxes` and `lists` like:

```
    [u'corporate & commercial', u'interiors']
```

Where the  `poject.ini` is

```
[fields.type]
label = Project type
type = checkboxes
choices = corporate & commercial, residential, interiors, public,hotel/tourism, university, art gallery, restoration, spa, auditorium,  installations, landscape
choice_labels = corporate & commercial, residential, interiors, public, hotel/tourism, university, art gallery, restoration, spa, auditorium,  installations, landscape
```

and the `project.html` has:

```
{% if this.type %}
<tr>
<th scope="row">Type</th>
<td>{{ this.type}}</td>
</tr>
{% endif %}
```

Where are those `[u'` in the ouput coming from? What am I missing?

Thank you

AR
(running lektor 3.0.1 on win 7/64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `{{ this.type }}`, you’re getting the full, raw results of your entire array.

Having looked at your example page, it looks like what you’re aiming to do is to call each item separately as a list. To do this, you need to loop through the array:

```
{% for item in this.type %}{{ item }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

This should output as ‘Item 1, Item 2, Item 3’. If you want to change the separator, edit the bit between `{% if not loop.last %}` and `{% endif %}`.

Comment: Could you add explanation to what this code does and how it helps solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `[u` indicates a list (or array). `this.type` is your list of choices, to get one item, you can use a for loop or a filter or such.

Comment: I'm sorry, for some reason I didn't see your answer (more than one year passed). Thank you.
With version 3.1.3 I got rid of the "u" but still have square brackets and quotes (see this sample, TYPE field: http://andrearicci.it/projects/new-bressanone-civic-library/).
Can you give me a sampleon how to fix it?
I hope I didn't forget everything I learned one year ago.Thank you